# SharePoint online people picker is not working. Not even for internal users

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker

SharePoint Online people picker is not resolving anyone. I'm a tenant administrator and even when I try to add myself whilst trying to create a new site collection, absolutely nothing resolves when assigning an administrator. I get the following error:

```
No results were found to match your search item. Please enter a new term or less specific term.
```

This also occurs when I use the smtp address. By the way, these are not external users I'm trying to add. They are all internal users.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if all the people pickers don't work.

Create a new list and add a column of type "User or group". Create a new list item and fill the column of type "User or group".

Is that working?

Comment: Hi Ganesh. I was able to successfully search but it looks like the only group that worked from the people picker was when select to search in "Tenant". I don't know why "All users" and so on, didn't work.

Comment: Could you offer a screenshot about the  "All users" and  "Tenant"?

Comment: I confirm it does not work (SharePoint Online, classic calendar forms, google chrome). If You press 'book icon' it does not search users. https://i.postimg.cc/cL6VwbsG/pp-search-not-working-2021-04-19-154714.png

Comment: @scot do You use SP-Responsive-UI?..

Comment: Described my temporary fix for PnP-Responsive (if Your case): https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/issues/244